# Как отключить поэкранный скролл если контента больше(swiper)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как отключить поэкранный скролл если контента больше(swiper)?

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]